# Differences between the iOS & Android versions of Guardian Cross?

Tags: guardian-cross

What are the differences between the Android and iOS versions of the game, besides the newer release date on Android?

I've read that not all hunting grounds are available on Android. There have been less coliseums of course, but I'm mainly interested in **gameplay** differences not a matter of having less contests (unless that means the game is missing some limited edition cards entirely?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the different release dates, there are some changes to various guardians, but for the most part they are the same.

Some major differences:

1. iOS has hacked cards and stones, so the values of good cards are much different and it's often unsafe to trade with people who do not have good reputation on forums. So far, the Android community has not seen hacked cards (or if they exist, Square Enix has not taken action).
2. Android is much newer and has a smaller player base, so it's easier and faster to work your way up to having a top deck

Comment: There are a lot more difference such as the stats & skills of cards (e.g. iOS Phoenix vs Android Phoenix), but a comprehensive answer would be quite long - and I've stopped playing GC so I can't validate it anyway. Accepting this as the best one so far :)

Answer (score 0):

No other changes than the ones you've mentioned.